# Trying to run file in Mac Terminal

Tags: terminal

I type the name of the file into the Terminal as just "set.bat" but get:.

-bash: run: command not found

I also fail to understand how this question fails to meet stack overflow's quality standards without this extra paragraph, so if someone could enlighten me about this also I would be much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make sure that you are in the same folder of the file to run, then you issue:

```
$ ./filetoexecute
```

mind the `./`, you'll have to write it because current directory is (almost never) in the path.

Additionally, `.bat` are Windows batch scripts, Bash will not understand them. You will have to look for a `.sh` (usual extension) or extensionless script.

Comment: Should I change the filename so it has .sh instead of .bat at the end?

Comment: No, they are different scripting language. You must have a shell script, not a batch script.